# AWS lambda Step Functions Activities and RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-rds, aws-step-functions

Is it possible to get Step Functions Activities and query RDS in a single lambda?

I've followed the VPC setting and can reach RDS and S3 endpoint in a single lambda.
(ref : https://gist.github.com/reggi/dc5f2620b7b4f515e68e46255ac042a7)

But when I write a lambda with getActivityTask and RDS, it will response a timeout for connecting to https://states.us-west-2.amazonaws.com:443.
(Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out)

I am sure I have already set the IAM role correctly.
I can't figure out if it's a configuration problem or it's simply not possible.

Thanks.

Comment: Which runtime are you using in your AWS Lambda?

Comment: @MaiKaY I am using Java 1.8

Comment: Launch lambda inside the VPC. Also you can refer this. https://blog.powerupcloud.com/automate-rds-and-aurora-mysql-processes-list-in-lambda-with-kms-736b2878349

Comment: @SQLadmin Thank you~ I have fixed this question. My use case should launch lambda in VPC and have to access AWS public endpoint, so I have also need to have public subnet and private subnet.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found out my VPC setting is wrong,

I missed the route tables setting for private subnet (which should be point to public subnet's NAT gateway), so can't connect to AWS public endpoint.